# Interval Operator in RxJava : Which part of code runs in background thread since I have subscribed on IO thread

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

- **What I am doing:** I am using the Iterval Operator from RxJava
- Output I have posted below
- **What I am trying to find out:** As you can see I have subscribed on `IO`
  thread. which part of code runs in background

**Code:**

```
class IntervalOperatorFragment : Fragment() {

    private val TAG = IntervalOperatorFragment::class.java.simpleName
    private var _binding: FragmentOperatorIntervalBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val INTERVAL_PERIOD = 1L
    private val MAXIMUM_PERIOD = 5L

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentOperatorIntervalBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        onClickListeners()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun onClickListeners() {
        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            subscribeToObservable()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the observable
     */
    private fun createObservable(): Observable<Long> {
        return Observable.interval(INTERVAL_PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                         .takeWhile { value ->
                             Timber.tag(TAG).d("Thread: %s",Thread.currentThread())
                             value <= MAXIMUM_PERIOD
                         }
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to the observable
     */
    private fun subscribeToObservable() {
        createObservable().subscribe(object : Observer<Long>{
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                Timber.tag(TAG).d("Subscribe Invoked")
            }

            override fun onNext(t: Long) {
                Timber.tag(TAG).d("Value: %s", t)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Timber.tag(TAG).e("ERROR: %s",e.message)
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                Timber.tag(TAG).d("Task is complete")
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-13 03:20:19.334 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Subscribe Invoked
2020-09-13 03:20:20.345 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:20.348 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Value: 0
2020-09-13 03:20:21.341 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:21.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Value: 1
2020-09-13 03:20:22.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:22.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Value: 2
2020-09-13 03:20:23.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:23.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Value: 3
2020-09-13 03:20:24.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:24.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Value: 4
2020-09-13 03:20:25.341 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:25.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Value: 5
2020-09-13 03:20:26.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-13 03:20:26.342 24452-24452/com.demo.code D/IntervalOperatorFragment: Task is complete
```

Comment: when you call `subscribe` that will return immediately on the calling thread and run on the io `Scheduler`.  The `interval` observable will run on the computation `Scheduler`, however you observe these on the main thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the Rx documentation: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html

> the SubscribeOn operator designates which thread the Observable will begin operating on, no matter at what point in the chain of operators that operator is called. ObserveOn, on the other hand, affects the thread that the Observable will use below where that operator appears.

If you put takeWhile before **observeOn** then it will use **IO** scheduler

```
Observable.interval(INTERVAL_PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .takeWhile { value ->
                Timber.tag(TAG).d("Thread: %s",Thread.currentThread())
                value <= MAXIMUM_PERIOD
            }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Anything below observeOn will use the Scheduler mentioned in observeOn operator.

Comment: Actually `takeWhile` will run on the `computation` scheduler, not `io` - as per my comment, `interval` runs on the computation scheduler by default, emitting values on that scheduler, and thus observed on that scheduler.